# Como configurar .htaccess para quitar las extensiones .html de la URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, enlace

**CONTEXTO**

Escribo este post porque tengo un pequeño problema con la URL del portfolio web que he desarrollado para un cliente. Dicho portfolio tiene las siguientes secciones: Home, Work, Info y Feed.

La cuestión es que he utilizado Wordpress, concretamente el template Semplice, para crear todas las secciones de la web excepto el Home, que lo he hecho "a mano" con código HTML, CSS y JS porque quería personalizarlo más allá de lo que me hubiese permitido el template de Wordpress.

**PROBLEMA**

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Al tener en mi carpeta public_html todos los archivos de Wordpress, y también el index que yo he creado, coincide que tengo el index.php (index de Wordpress, no puedo borrarlo porque carga el resto de secciones aunque no lo visualice en el navegador) y el index.html (el index que yo he creado y al que quiero que se acceda al entrar en https://nombredemisitio.com).

He conseguido que acceda a mi index.html al poner simplemente la URL de la página, escribiendo una línea en el .htaccess. Por lo tanto, cuando escribo en el navegador https://nombredemisitio.com me redirige automáticamente a https://nombredemisitio.com/index.html.

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://gonzzzalo.com/index.html [L,R=301]
```

**LO QUE NECESITO CONSEGUIR**

Me gustaría saber si es posible borrar de dicha URL el index.html pero que siga redirigiendo a este archivo en lugar de al index.php de Wordpress (que es a donde te dirigiría al entrar en la URL https://nombredemisitio.com si no hubiese añadido la línea en .htaccess).

Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta para esto es agregar lo siguiente en el .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Lo que haces con esto es decir cual es el archivo principal.

Comment: De acuerdo, genial! Aunque ahora me surge el siguiente problema haciendo lo que comentabas: al hacerlo, en efecto, se redirige como yo quiero, y se queda tal cual https://nombredemisitio.com. Pero el problema es que ahora no puedo acceder al admin de Wordpress como lo hacía antes, escribiendo https://nombredemisitio.com/admin. Si lo hago, me da error 404. Dónde esta mi panel de administrador de Wodrpress? Cómo accedo a él?

Comment: hace una modificación pone lo siguiente: 

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Lo que estarias haciendo es que tome segun orden de prioridad, te tira el 404, porque en /admin buscar un index.html forzado al poner lo que te mencione al no encontrar un index.html toma el siguiente en este caso index.php

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Lo he solucionad con la línea que me has puesto tú. Me surgió un pequeño problema que es que no me cargaba el certificado SSL (https) en el home de la página por algún motivo, así que se lo he forzado yo añadiendo esta línea al .htaccess además de lo que me has recomendado.

Comment: Rewriterule ^$ https://nombredemisitio.com/index.html [l,r=301]

Comment: Tambien lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera: 

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.susitioweb.com/$1 [R,L]`

y te ahorras el tener algún plugin para el wordpress.